# I want to resize my toolbar

Tags: iphone, orientation

I want to resize my toolbar when orientation changes.
But I have faced a difficult problem.

I have two view controllers.
The first view controller have a button. When this button touches, the second view will appear on display. These view controllers belong to a navigation controller.

The first view controller make navigation bar show. And second view controller make navigation bar hide.

*important methods in the first view controller*

```
- ( void ) viewWillAppear: ( BOOL )animated {

      [ super viewWillAppear: animated ];
      [ [ [ self navigationController ] navigationBar ] setHidden: NO ];

      UIButton *nextButton;
      nextButton = [ UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect ];
      [ nextButton setFrame: CGRectMake( 50.0, 50.0, 200.0, 150.0 ) ];
      [ nextButton setTag: 100 ];
      [ nextButton addTarget: self action: @selector( touchedNextButton: ) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside ];
      [ [ self view ] addSubview: nextButton ];
}

- ( BOOL ) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: ( UIInterfaceOrientation )interfaceOrientation {

   // Return YES for supported orientations
   BOOL iResult;
   iResult = ( ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ) || ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) ||
                       ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ) );
   return iResult;
```

}

```
    - ( void ) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: ( UIInterfaceOrientation )fromInterfaceOrientation {

        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] orientation ];

        UIButton *button = ( UIButton * )[ [ self view ] viewWithTag: 100 ];

        switch ( orientation ) {
            case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
                [ button setFrame: CGRectMake( 50.0, 50.0, 200.0, 150.0 ) ];
                break;
            case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                [ button setFrame: CGRectMake( 50.0, 50.0, 200.0, 150.0 ) ];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

*important methods in the second view controller*

```
- ( void ) viewDidLoad {

    [ [ [ self navigationController ] navigationBar ] setHidden: YES ];

    UIImage *imageBackArrow_iPhone = [ UIImage nonCachedImageNamed: @"backArrow_iPhone.png" ];
    NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithCapacity: 5 ];
    [ toolbarItems addObject: [ [ [ UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithImage: imageBackArrow_iPhone style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target: self
                                                                       action: @selector( touchedBackArrowButton ) ] autorelease ] ];
        UIToolbar *toolbar = [ [ UIToolbar alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 0.0, 416.0, 320.0, 44.0 ) ];
        [ toolbar setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin ];
        [ toolbar setItems: toolbarItems ];
        [ toolbarItems release ];
        [ [ self view ] addSubview: toolbar ];
        [ toolbar release ];
    }
}
```

The rest methods in second view controller are similar to the first view contoller.

[image]

[image]

After starting on portrait mode in the first view controller, I touched the next button. Changing Orientations work fine.
(The first screen shot)

But starting on portrait mode in the first view controller, I changed to landscape mode.
Then I touched the next button, this made weird layout.
(The second screen shot)

I don't know what makes this problem.

Please let me know your experiences. Your advices will make me awake.
Thank you for your reading.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks very unlikely.... but
you can try resizing stuff in your viewWillAppear Method of your viewcontroller as well.
This could help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use autoresizing masks?

Comment: I'm using autoresizing mask. [ toolbar setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin ];